# Knowing if the finite intersection of half spaces forms a closed polytope?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, polytopes

Say you have $N$ half-spaces $P$ in some dimension. We want to know if the intersection of all such half spaces results in a closed or open polytope, and if open, we want to introduce the minimum number of half spaces that close it.

I have been trying to find a solution to this problem for a while. Many resources such as [this one](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2020/cmsc754/Lects/lect06-duality.pdf), do mention the fact that the polytope may be open. But none that I find tell you how to tell from the get go if it is open or not given the half spaces that make up the polytope.

I need to solve this at least in 3D but ideally in arbitrary dimensions.

Comment: In any event, I am not quite sure what you are asking, but *I think* the answer to your question is $n+1$ (you can completely bound an $n$-simplex with $n+1$ half-spaces).  Let $P_j = (0,\dotsb,0,1,0,\dotsb,0)$ be the point in $n$-dimensional space which has coordinates all zero, except in the $j$-th position, and let $P_0$ denote the origin.  Any $n$ of these points will define a co-dimension 1 subspace; delete the half-space which does not contain the last point.  The intersection of these $n+1$ half-spaces is the convex hull of the $n+1$ points.

Comment: In dimension $2$, the result of this process is a right triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, and $(0,1)$.  In dimension $3$, the result is the tetrahedron with vertices $(0,0,0)$, $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(0,0,1)$.  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex .

Comment: @XanderHenderson I am not asking for the minimum *number* I am asking for the actual half planes. As in, I am actually trying to reconstruct the polytope in a computer.

i.e. I am given a bunch of oriented planes in 3d, I need to turn all those planes into  explicit geoemtry. To do that I must ensure they form a closed polytope. To do that I need to figure out if the polytope is unbounded, and if ti is, I need to add more planes to close it btu want to add the strict minimum required.

Comment: Well, in general, I don't know that there is any good answer to your question.  If your half-spaces coincide or are bounded by "parallel" co-dimension 1 subspaces, then it will take $n$ additional half-spaces to bound a region in $n$-dimensional space.  I don't think that a more satisfactory answer is possible without additional constraints.

Comment: The problem does have a most natural solution to where to add the additional vectors, I just don't know how to express it properly beyond dimension 2.

In dimension 2 the cases are having 1, 2 or 3 "good vectors". If only one vector is good, add 2 vectors such that they have the same angle (i.e. make an equilateral triangle), if 2 vectors are given then they form an obtuse angle and an acute angle.  Bisect the obtuse angle to add the third vector.

I.e. in 2D you just add vectors in such a way that their angles add to 180 but no angle is > 180.

Comment: Linear programming algorithms can solve this problem. In dimension $n$, one test for boundedness is to solve the $n+1$ LP problems of maximizing $a\cdot x$, for $a$ taking  , for example the $n$ normals to the coordinate (hyper)planes, and $(1,1,...,1)$. The example is just to form a simplex. The polytope is closed if and only if all these LP problems have finite optimum. If the algorithm is the simplex, then it can also be used to remove superfluous inequalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your halfspaces have normal vectors $a_1,...,a_n\in\Bbb R^d$.

The idea is as follows:

1. check whether all normal vectors lie in some subspace. If so, then your polytope is a sort of infinite cylinder, hence open.
2. check whether all normal vectors lie in a common halfspace. If so then your polytope is open, otherwise closed.

**To 1.**
Check whether the matrix $A:=(a_1,...,a_n)\in\Bbb R^{n\times d}$ has rank $d$. If it has rank $r < d$, then $P$ is open. You can fix it by adding at least $d-r+1$ hyperplanes with affinely idenpendent normal vectors in $\ker(A)$.

**To 2.**
If 1. checks out then we know that the $a_i$ span $\Bbb R^d$, and so if they were to lie in a common halfspace, then $\mathbf a:=a_1+\cdots + a_n$ lies in the interior of the halfspace, and $-\mathbf a$ strictly outside of it. To reject this hypothesis, you try to find $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n\ge 0$ so that $\alpha_1 a_1+\cdots+\alpha_n a_n=-\mathbf a$. This comes down to solving a linear program with some standard procedures. If there is a solution, then $P$ is closed, otherwise open. In the latter case you can add $-\mathbf a$ as a normal vector to close your polytope.

---

**Addendum**

The linear program that I am talking about might look something like this, and a solver will need to tell you whether there is a feasible solution in the first place.

\begin{align}
\text{max}\;& 0
\\\text{s.t.}\; & \alpha_1 a_1+\cdots+\alpha_n a_n=-\mathbf a
\\& \alpha_1,...,\alpha_n\ge 0
\end{align}

Comment: On point 2 did you mean a_n? The last term is confusing to me.

Comment: @Makogan Yes. Fixed it

Comment: would you be able to edit your answer to make the LP mor explicit? I will admit I tried setting it up but i think I made a silly mistake.

Comment: @Makogan Does this help?

Comment: yes perfect, thank you so much